# Opening a text file and returning a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a function that opens a file with the given name and return a dictionary where the keys are the first part in the file and the values are a list readings. 
eg:

file has:
Queensland, 30.5
NSW, 20.3
SA, 55
Queensland, 52.3
NSW, 55.2

I created a function to open the file, how do I write a for loop to go through every line in the file and split the details into 2 using a comma, then add this as a new entry to my blank dictionary. The result needs to be displayed as a dictionary.

Comment: Welcoome to StackOverflow! When asking questions, you should post what code you have already written, so it is easier to fix your problem. It doesn't have to be the full code, only the part you think is relevant to your problem. This way, answers can also adapt better to your existing code.

Comment: your file seem to follow a CSV structure, you can consider reading it as a CSV file. Documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html .

Answer (score 0):

So for this Text file,

```
Queensland, 30.5 
NSW, 20.3 
SA, 55 
Queensland, 52.3 
NSW, 55.2
```

You want your output like this, If I am correct

```
{'Queensland': [30.5, 52.3], 'SA': [55.0], 'NSW': [20.3, 55.2]}
```

Then the corresponding Code is:

```
def fun(file_name):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as robj:
        lines = robj.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        processed_line = line.split(', ')
        if not my_dict.has_key(processed_line[0]):
            my_dict[processed_line[0]] =[]
        my_dict[processed_line[0]].append(float(processed_line[1]))

    return my_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fun('textfile.txt'))
```

Comment: That fixed the code. However, it didn't return the dictionary key as a group and also showed it as {'Queensland, 30.5\n' : [], 'NSW, 20.3\n' : [], 'SA, 55\n' : [], 'Queensland, 52.3\n' : [], 'NSW, 55.2\n' : []}

Comment: State is the key and the reading is the value in the dictionary

Comment: If state is the key and reading is the value then your dictionary should be something like this `{'Queensland: [30.5, 52.3] , 'NSW': [20.3, 55.2], 'SA': [55]}` .

 If you want to club your state and reading, then you can try nested dict like this `{Queensland: {30.5: [], 52.3: []}, NSW: {20.3: [], 55.2: []}, SA: {55: []}}`

Comment: I am trying to output the first dictionary but for some reason it returns the dictionary as a nested one. This is the output I want {'Queensland: [30.5, 52.3] , 'NSW': [20.3, 55.2], 'SA': [55]} but with the above code i'm getting {'Queensland, 30.5\n' : [], 'NSW, 20.3\n' : [], 'SA, 55\n' : [], 'Queensland, 52.3\n' : [], 'NSW, 55.2\n' : []}

Comment: Edited the answer... hope that helps :)

Comment: .has_key is given me an error attribute error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'. Not sure why I can't figure it out?

Comment: Try running in python 2. has_key() was removed in python3. In Python 3, you can also use  `if not processed_line[0] in my_dict:` instead of  `if not my_dict.has_key(processed_line[0]):` to achieve the same :)